# Использовать объект JS как контейнер

Tags: объекты, javascript

```
var i;
var current_report = { Info :
                            [
                                {
                                    solutionNumber : '',
                                    ownerName : '',
                                    lastUpdated : ''
}]};
$(data).find('table.solutions_list tbody tr').each(function(){  
i = 0;
current_report.Info[i] = {
                                solutionNumber : $(this).find('td.fullNumber').text(),
                                ownerName : $(this).find('td.ownerFullName').text(),
                            lastUpdated : $(this).find('td.updateDateFormat').text()
                            }
i++;
```

Пытаюсь таким образом создать объект, который нужно использовать как контейнер для добавления записей, каждая из которых состоит из трёх строк.
Селекторы работают 100%, проблема в том, что я что-то не так делаю с объектом.
Вместо данных по запросу, к примеру, `Current_report.Info[0]`, он выдаёт `Object object` вместо трёх отправленных ему строк.

Буду признателен за подсказку.

Comment: @RobinBobin, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

```
Current_report.Info[0].solutionNumber
```

И будет все нормально